# Как сделать указатель для игры 6а библиотеке sfml под С++?

Tags: sfml

Друзья, у меня проблема. Ищу на оф. сайте библиотеке sfml пример с кодом по созданию указателя в игре, но ничего не могу найти. Сам пока малоопытен потому,что изучаю sfml мало. У меня просьба, если кто может помочь, то помогите.

Comment: @ДаниилНовенький, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Иой модуль телепатии подсказывает мне, что вы хотите отрисовывать управляемый мышью курсор в окне игры, это так?

Comment: именно так.

Answer (score 0):

если ты имеешь виду указатель мыши, то все просто , загрузи как обычно текстуру указателя в sprite (Sprite.setTexture(путь)),далее отключи курсор по умолчанию,window.setMouseCursorVisible(false),потом просто в главном игровом цилке добавить это

```
Vector2i pixelPos = Mouse::getPosition(window);
Vector2f pos = window.mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos);
```

так ты получишь координаты курсора. А теперь просто перед отрисовкой sprite-а , напиши sprite.setPosition(pos.x,pos.y);